# Rx js multiple subscribers query

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have one service that return Observable of one token and many subscribers that calls this service and try to get this token. 
If I already have token in memory I just return it if not - making new request, save token and return Observable this this token.

The issue with many multiple call of service in one time. So Some of this subscribers recieved different tokens.  Maybe exist some way in RxJs for creating some query for each request after first, waiting for response and send value to all subscribers?

I will be very appropriates for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the observable once using `publishLast` to make it "shareable".  Give this observable to ALL CALLERS even if the token is already available.

```
var _tokenObservable;
var _subscription;
getToken() {
    if (!_tokenObservable) {
        // first time in, create the observable
        _tokenObservable = makeCallToGetTokenObservable().publishLast();
        // start the request
        _subscription = shared.connect();
    }
    return _tokenObservable;
}
```